# Numpy array coordinates in a set

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, set

I'm working with OpenCV in python 2.7.5. I have implemented a sliding window for my image by using the following line of code:

```
subImage = image[yStart:yEnd, xStart:xEnd]
```

Where `image` is the full grayscale image and `yStart` is the starting y coordinate, `yEnd` is the ending y coordinate, `xStart` is the starting x coordinate, and `xEnd` is the ending x coordinate. `subImage` the cropped image (the part of the image in the window) from the given coordinates.

What I want to do is add all the coordinates in this `subImage` which are above a certain threshold value to a python set of seen coordinates. How would I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean grayscale image rather than binary image?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any OpenCV, but in plain NumPy I would do it like this.

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.bool)
mask[yStart:yEnd, xStart:xEnd] = True
mask &= image > threshold
coords = np.where(mask)
```

Depending on your application you may want your coordinates in the form:

```
coords = zip(*coords)
```